# javascript property updation dynamically

Tags: javascript

I am learning javascript and was trying few basic examples. I found some strange behavior and thought this forum would help me in understanding the solution better.

I have created an object as below:

```
var school={
  name:"purnapramati",
  location:"girinagar",
  'state-name':"karnataka",
  proximity:true
}
```

Now, I add a property dynamically like below:

```
school.country="india";
```

When is print the school object, I see the updated country attribute with India as value.

Now, I try to add a property to proximity attribute:

```
school.proximity.distance="less than 4kms";
```

This time the distance attribute is not added to the proximity attribute and not reflected in the school object too.

Why is this behavior? Please explain me. I know this is a very basic question but I am looking for a convincing answer/justification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that your `proximity` property is not an object, so it cannot have attributes.  It is a boolean with a single value.

I'm not sure what `proximity` being `true` represents, but you could do something like:

```
var school={
  name:"purnapramati",
  location:"girinagar",
  'state-name':"karnataka",
  proximity: {
      nearby: true
  }
}
```

after which you could give it additional properties as you are trying with `distance`.

Or using your original structure you could do something like:

```
school.proximity = { distance: "less than 4kms" };
```

But then you will lose that `true` value unless you store it in another attribute.

Comment: ok. What if i want to make that an object dynamically? Can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

`school.proximity = {distance:"less than 4kms"} ;`